# How to define in which category display React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, web-frontend

I have React component `<Banner />` which is just an image (clickable and redirects to one of the categories), shown on the Home Page and belongs to 1 category eg. Ice-Cream (I have sidebar-menu with categories).

How can i check in which category to display this banner?

```
var Banner = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var toCategory = "/favourites";
    var imageName = "Magnum Banner";
    return (
      <section className="banner" onClick={ this.props.onClick }>
        <a href={toCategory}>
          <img src={ window.assets['banner.png'] } width="1030" alt={imageName} ref="Banner" />
        </a>
      </section>
    );
  }
});
```

I was thinking about this way `(this.state.ShowBanner) ? <Banner /> : null`, 
setting an Initial state to `false` in CategoryList component and then if `window.location(?)` equal to path in Banner component - setState to true

Pls help me with this issue. Thanks

Comment: Hello, first: `{ this.state.showBanner ? : null}` is not how the ternary operator  works, you're missing a bit between `?` and `:`. Secondly it seems you could do with reading [thinking in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html).

Comment: Sorry did a mistake
? : <Banner />

Comment: No problem, I suggest you try something first and then get back to us here with a concrete error or example.

Comment: do you use react-router?